# Exclude flag in zip not excluding directory as expected

Tags: linux, zip

I'm trying to zip every file in my **current** directory to `deploy.zip` using the command:

```
zip -r deploy.zip -x "**/node_modules/**"
```

This command doesn't work and still zips all the node_modules and it's descendant folders and files.
This command is basically running on the GitHub Action panel.

What's wrong in here?

Comment: @Inian the node_modules is in my current dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your exclude glob expression isn't quite right. The expression `**/node_modules/**` looks for absolute filenames from the search path that has the string `/node_modules/` to be present. But running the `zip` from your current path won't include the leading `/` for any of the file/directory names under `node_modules`. I would suggest doing it as `'*node_modules*'` or `'./node_modules/*'` or `'node_modules/*'` for your exclude path definition.

Also note that using `**` in your glob pattern doesn't mean the same as using simple wild card expansion as `*`. The former has a special meaning in `zip` when `--wild-stop-dirs` option is enabled. See [zip(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip)